# Creating deterministic set of UUIDs in python

Tags: python

I need to create a set of static UUIDs in python which is each time the same.

So I created the following function:

```py
def uuid_generator():
    seed = 2459234408052414943112311245669091401656 # Just a large random number
    while True:
        yield uuid.UUID(int=seed)
        seed += 1
```

This function works fine so far, but I don't like the fact that the UUIDs are just upcounting by this implementation.

So I'm wondering how to change the UUID seed value each time the function is called, so the generated UUIDs

- Remain deterministic
- Are each time different (for a relatively small number of calls, let's say 1000 UUIDs)
- Changed in a way they are not just counting up by one.

Comment: Create an array of seeds, randomly generated using a single seed, then iterate over that array in your while True loop

Comment: @nicomp Thank you for the hint. I forgot that random also behaves deterministic (based on the seed value). I posted an answer using random with a constant seed to generate the UUIDs.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comment to the original question I found the following solution for the problem:

```py
def uuid_generator():
    random.seed(633458965612378623578) # Some random number

    while True:
        yield uuid.UUID(int=random.getrandbits(128))
```